# Facebook like button not showing up on page

Tags: html, css, facebook

Hey guys Im trying to figure out the like button code. Used the wizard on facebook. Button still will not show up. I mean even with a simple HTML like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://facebook.com/jameshenrypcsolutions" data-width="125" data-height="40" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div>
```

any clue on why that button is not showing up? Thats directly copied from the wizard with nothing else in the body and it still does not work....

Answer (score 0):

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dUpPk/)

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://facebook.com/jameshenrypcsolutions" data-width="The pixel width of the plugin" data-height="The pixel height of the plugin" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-send="false"></div>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem and your demo isn't working anymore